# Почему компилятор выдает ошибку? c++

Tags: c++, sdl

Здравствуйте. Не пойму, в чем ошибка. Все библиотеки подключены(SDL2.lib, SDL2main.lib). Все инициализировано. Почему не работает?
Вывод из компилятора:

```
> 1>SDL2main.lib(SDL_windows_main.obj) : error LNK2019: ссылка на
> неразрешенный внешний символ _SDL_main в функции _main_utf8
> 1>C:\Users\alleksh_\Desktop\cppprojects &
> backups\games\SDLGame\Debug\SDLGame.exe : fatal error LNK1120:
> неразрешенных внешних элементов: 1
```

Вот исходный код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL.h>
int main()
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0) {return 1;}
    SDL_Window *win = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 640, 480, SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (win == nullptr) {return 1;}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить аргументы к `main(int argc, char *args[])`

Comment: А может надо extern "C"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вы используете библиотеку SDLmain, которая задает платформо-зависимую точку входа, парсит аргументы командной строки (переводя их в utf-8), и затем вызывает точку входа SDL приложения. Соответственно в своем коде вместо `main()` следует определить функцию

```
int SDL_main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

SDL еще переопределяет макросом `main` как `SDL_main`, но при этом набор параметров должен обязательно соответствовать. Это не очень хорошая практика, поэтому лучше писать название функции полностью, а после инклюда `SDL.h` убирать этот макрос дописав `#undef main`.