Значение типа SDL_Window* нельзя присвоить сущности типа vk_engine::SDL_Window*
Как я понял, проблема с моей областью имен vk_engine. Возможно это SDL недоволен чем-то, ведь если использовать GLFW, то все нормально. Проблема решается только если создавать переменную вместе с созданием окна. Проблема в следующей строке:

_window = SDL_CreateWindow(_engineApplicationName, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, _widthApplication, _heightApplication, SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN);


Вот код engineApplication.h:
#pragma once

#include <iostream>
#include <validator.h>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

namespace vk_engine {

    class engineApplication {

    public: 

        engineApplication(uint32_t widthApplication, uint32_t heightApplication);
        ~engineApplication();

        engineApplication(const engineApplication&) = delete;
        engineApplication& operator=(const engineApplication&) = delete;

        uint32_t _widthApplication;
        uint32_t _heightApplication;
        const char* _engineApplicationName = "Hello";

        void run();

        void init_application();
        bool shouldCloseApplication() { return true; }

    private:

        struct SDL_Window* _window{ nullptr };


    };

}

Вот код engineApplication.cpp:
#include <engineApplication.h>

#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_vulkan.h>

#include <iostream>

namespace vk_engine {

    engineApplication::engineApplication(uint32_t widthApplication,
        uint32_t heightApplication) :
        _widthApplication(widthApplication),
        _heightApplication(heightApplication)
    {
        init_application();
    }

    void engineApplication::run()
    {

    }

    void engineApplication::init_application()
    {
        SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
        _window = SDL_CreateWindow(_engineApplicationName, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, _widthApplication, _heightApplication, SDL_WINDOW_VULKAN);
        //validator::check_condition(false, "");
    }

    engineApplication::~engineApplication()
    {

    }

}


struct SDL_Window* _window{ nullptr }; -> SDL_Window * _window{}; и инклюды SDL в заголовочный файл не забудьте добавить.

Если я добавлю SDL_Window * _window{}; то появляется другая ошибка: _window: необъявленный идентификатор. Если я добавлю инклюды в заголовочный файл, мол, SDL.h, то у меня вылетает прога с одной ошибкой: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ main в функции "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ). Если я попробую направиться в SDL.h с заголовочного файла, то VS говорит что нет такого файла по пути, только если на cpp стороне engineApplication.

Все правильно, вам необходимо было понять смысл ошибки и разобраться с ошибкой "ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ", а не пытаться что-то городить наобум.

Я просто считал, что смысл задавать вопрос в том, чтобы могли помочь если не трудно. Я не понимаю, откуда исходит ошибка, но main.cpp у меня правильный. У меня эта ошибка появляется сразу как только я добавляю в заголовочный файл engineApplication.h #include<SDL.h>.

"У меня эта ошибка появляется сразу как только я добавляю в заголовочный файл engineApplication.h #include<SDL.h>." - да, но она появляется не из-за того, что #include<SDL.h> добавлен ошибочно.  По проблеме "ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ" есть популярный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/536546 О, оказывается конкретно про этот случай с SDL тоже уже были вопросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/757995 и https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1081627, так что это дубликат получается...

Спасибо вам большое, оказывается нужен был макрос SDL_MAIN_HANDLED перед включением SDL.h дабы избежать перезаписи основной main.

SDL_MAIN_HANDLED - это немного костыль. По двум ссылкам, которые вам дали, не предлагают его добавлять.

SDL_MAIN_HANDLED стоит использовать, только если вы сами будите предоставлять точку входа на всех платформах и сами производить действия, которые там обычно производит SDL.
